# Correct way of using Flask config class with from_object() for development/production/testing environment selection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I saw many forum posts (including the docs) showing how to use the config class with inheritance and it looks really clean. I would love to use it, however none of these explain how to load which config file according to the environment.

For example, having a config class in config.py:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

and then in app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config.DevelopmentConfig")

# Overwrite some config on the fly if needed with .env
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS')
```

However the problem with this is how do you call `app.config.from_object("config.DevelopmentConfig")` or `app.config.from_object("config.ProductionConfig")` automatically without having to change the code? should it be with yet another .env file that contains which config to use? Or should I have `app_dev.py`, `app_prod.py`, etc., where unfortunately lots of code would be duplicated?